# Use Wireshark for debugging HTTP/HTTPS

Tags: http, networking, https, fiddler, wireshark

I want to capture HTTP or HTTPS requests on my created bridge connection. But Fiddler doesn't captures requests on bridge connection.

1. How can I view only HTTP requests on Wireshark?
2. How can I view response of http/https requests on Wireshark?
3. How can I view the requested query on Wireshark?

I want to use Wireshark like Fiddler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what a **Wireshark** window looks like by default (using version 1.12.3 in this example):

[image: Wireshark Window]

From top to bottom you have:

- Menu Toolbar
- Main Toolbar
- Filter Toolbar
- Packet List
- Packet Details
- Packet Bytes
- Status Bar

In the Filter toolbar (where the input box named *Filter* lies) you can write filters to keep only the packets you want to inspect:

> 1. How can I view only http requests on wireshark?

`http.request`

> 2. How can I view response of http/https requests on wireshark?

`http.response`

Enhancing your filter with the IP address of yor NIC would also help reduce the amount of packets displayed:
`http.response and ip.addr == x.x.x.x`

You can also view both request and responses at the same time (as you can see in the image) using the filter: `http.request or http.response`.

> 3. How can I view the requested query on wireshark?

If you select a packet in the **Packet List** section, detailed information is displayed in the **Packet Details** section where you have all the information about that packet that you need.

Comment: Am I correct that this filter (http.request or http.response) doesn't work anymore for http2? I am seeing traffic coming by when accessing http1 sites but http2 is not showing up.